# Hellinger distance between 3-parameter Weibull distributions

Tags: metric-spaces, information-theory

I found Wikipedia to have listed Hellinger distance between pairs of 2-parameter Weibull distributions sharing the same shape parameter

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellinger_distance

However, I wasn't able to find any information on Helinger distance between pairs of 3-parameter Weibull distributions (with the 3rd parameter being the location parameter), and that no parameters are shared between the pair of Weibulls.

I was trying to derive for one but I failed miserably, can anyone point out a source that might have some information on this? Or is anyone able to derive a closed form here? Thanks.

**I was also looking for/trying to derive the closed form of KL-divergence between pairs of 3-parameter Weibull distributions, as all papers only derive the closed form for the 2-parameter Weibulls....